# Script to monitor mounted usb key

Tags: linux, udev, usb-flash-drive, inotify

### My issue

Hello,

I'am currently working a project to monitor files copied to a usb key. I'm using a udev to start an inotify script.

I'm currently struggling to find when the usb key is mounted and get the path (`/media/user/<usb-name>`). The hardest part is that on Ubuntu 22.04, the key is not auto mounted when plugged in the computer. So I have to wait for the user to mount it. (Using the `mount` command or trough `Nautilus` by clicking on it.).

So the scirpt is running :

```bash
while true; do
    local mountpoint=$(findmnt -rn -S "$deviceNode" -o TARGET)
    # devide node is /dev/sda1

    if [[ -n "$mountpoint" ]]; then
        echo "USB device $deviceNode is mounted at $mountpoint" >> "$logFile"
    else
        echo "USB device $deviceNode is not mounted" >> "$logFile"
    fi
    ((counter++))
    echo "Iteration: $counter" >> "$logFile"
    sleep 3
done
```

### My questions :

The issue is that the script stops after 2 iteration. If the sleep is 1, it's stops after 4 iteration. I don't understand why. Does someone have a clue ?

But my approach might not be the best. Is there another way to do what I want ?

---

### Scripts

`/etc/udev/rules.d/99-usb-stick.rules`

```bash
ACTION=="add", SUBSYSTEM=="block", ENV{DEVTYPE}=="partition", RUN+="/opt/data/wrapper.sh %N"
```

`/opt/data/wrapper.sh`

```bash
#!/bin/bash
# wrapper.sh

# Run the actual script in the background
/opt/data/test.sh $1 &
```

I'm using this approach because udev is paused while a program is running [as explain here, part advanced topics](http://www.reactivated.net/writing_udev_rules.html)

`/opt/data/test.sh`

```bash
#!/bin/bash
# test.sh

# All my code goes here
```

I hope that I have been clear, it's one of my first post.

Thanks.